# ggplot: How to add the number of counts on top of histogram bars when using cut()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to figure out how to add counts on top of the histogram bins as I also use cuts().

Age is one of the variables in my data set (continuous, range 23~99), and I need to produce a histogram with 8 bins, each indicating a combined age group (<30, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60-69, 70-79 ,"80-89","90-99").

I was able to figure out a code for everything *except* for adding the count on top of each bin.

The code I normally use for adding counts is something like this:

```
    geom_text(stat= "count", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1, size=3)         
    + ylim(c(0,300))
```

However, I don't think stat="count" works in this case.

The code I show below works fine except for the last two lines (my attempt to add the counts).

Thanks to everyone for their help!!

```
    output <- cut(df$age, breaks = seq(20,100, by= 10), labels = c("
    <30","30-39","40-49", "50-59","60-69","70-79","80-89","90-99"))


    table(output) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = output, y = Freq, fill=output)) + 
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("firebrick1", "chocolate1", 
    "yellow1", "springgreen3", "steelblue1",
    "navyblue", "darkorchid1", "darkmagenta"),
                 name="Age group",
                 labels=c("<30","30-39","40-49", "50-59",
    "60-69","70-79","80-89","90-99")) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(title="Histogram for Age") +
    labs(x="Age Group", y="Frequency") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
       geom_text(stat= "count", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1,         
    size=3) +
    ylim(c(0,300))

    Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

Comment: It's not an histogram, it's a barplot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate the frequencies with `stat = "count"`, you already have them in your data, and in fact you're already using them in `aes(x = output, y = Freq, fill=output)`. So you can do:

```
geom_text(aes(label=Freq), vjust=-1, size=3)
```